# Is there a more updated version of the book "Genome?"

Tags: human-genome, book-recommendation

I read the book Genome by Matt Ridley for my AP biology course. I found it fascinating, although it seems another book must have been written on the topic since 1999. Anything you can recommend?

Comment: How much science have you had sense AP bio?  It would effect my a recommendation.  More details are always nice for a question like this, so that an answer doesn't seem primarily opinion based.

Comment: Not much. I took it last school year, so I finished it last May. What I liked about Genome is that it didn't require a ton of understanding of genetics and explained many things without using advanced science jargon. That being said, I myself could probably take on something a bit more challenging with the help of Wikipedia and my science teacher.

Comment: What is AP biology?

Comment: @WYSIWYG Advanced Placement Biology. High school Biology course equivalent to a first semester college Bio course. The syllabus is defined by CollageBoard.